# Android set margin/padding for contents (text) instead of a container (EditText)

Tags: android, android-edittext, padding

What I want to do is add some top margin/padding before THE TEXT, and not for the entire container:

#### Code is as simple as:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/mightyText"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="left|top"
     android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textMultiLine"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:paddingRight="20dp"
     android:paddingBottom="80dp"
     android:background="#fff" />
```

#### Produces outputs:

[image: Desired behaviour]

> Once it's on top it works great. I have equal paddings for sides and top...

---

[image: Naughty padding ;(]

> ...but when I scroll, the padding stays glued to the container instead of going up with the text

---

### And that's how I'd like it to be (when not scrolled to top):

[image: Proper behavior]

How do I change it, so it scrolls with the text instead of always being visible?

Comment: great question!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put it in ScrollView, which will automatically take care of the scroll. EditText won't be responsible for that, so his padding will work as you wish. Try the code below:

```
<ScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <EditText android:id="@+id/mightyText"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="left|top"
               android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textMultiLine"
               android:paddingLeft="20dp"
               android:paddingRight="20dp"
               android:paddingBottom="80dp"
               android:background="#fff" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: padding should do this automatically!! This answer works now though.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an EditText?  If the user will not be editing it, then use a normal TextView with a top padding of 10dp and wrap it in a ScrollView.

As far as I know, there's no way to set an internal padding on the top of an EditText.

Comment: The user **will** be editing this for sure. If it was TextView I wouldn't have my problem at all :).

Answer (score 0):

On ViewGroup there is attribute called `clipToPadding`. Docs says:
`Defines whether the ViewGroup will clip its drawing surface so as to exclude the padding area. This property is set to true by default.` Try to find out something similar in EditText.

Comment: That actually was a good idea, unfortunately there's nothing similar for EditText...